# is that possible to use instruction pivot in dataset.xsd

Tags: sql, dataset, pivot

when i put this select command into my dataset.xsd

```
  select *
from
  (
    select TR_DEB,TR_FIN, T_UNITE.LIBELLE as LibUnite, ZONE, MONTANT 
    from TARIF_COURANT
    LEFT JOIN T_UNITE ON TARIF_COURANT.UNITE = T_UNITE.NO_ID
    where NO_CLIENT = '440104239' and zone in (1,2,3,4,6)
  )as T
pivot
  (
    min(MONTANT) for ZONE in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[6]) 
  )as P ORDER BY P.TR_DEB
```

it said that dataset cannot acepted pivot. is there the other way ?

i try to put into Store procedure, but i can not clic the first option. [image: see image]

thanks you in advance

Comment: Can you try putting in the column names explicitly, i.e., `select blah,blah,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]`?

Comment: instead of pivoting in the dataset, can you create a stored proc on the server side and then add that to the dataset?